# Replace Non-letters except apostrophe in java

Tags: java, regex, replace, ascii

I have a few strings that contain non-letters.

```
String A = "it's. (fish)[]//;!"
```

I want to return a string that says:

```
it's fish
```

I have used the String.replace() method but it's a bit tedious. I also tried using

```
 A.replaceAll("\\W", "")
```

but it removes the apostrophe. Is there a simple way of removing all non-letters while keeping the apostrophe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a Java specific construct here:

```
A.replaceAll("[\\W&&[^']]", "")
```

The specific construct here is the character class: `x&&[y]`, meaning: match `x` and `y`. `y`  can be anything that is valid within a character class.

Available since Java 5 if I recall correctly.

Answer (score 2):

You can add `'` to a negated character class with `\\w`. I notice that you are not replacing a whitespace. Then add that too to the character class:

```
String A = "it's. (fish)[]//;!"
A = A.replaceAll("[^\\w' ]", ""); 
System.out.println(A);  // it's fish
```

This will replace the characters that are not `\\w`, `'` or whitespace.

---

Or you can use intersection of character class and a negated character class:

```
[\\W&&[^' ]]
```

but it only works in Java regex engine. I don't know if there is any other regex engine supporting this.

**P.S:** BTW, `A` is not a very good variable name.

Comment: how would I modify this such that this only works if the puncutation is after only 1 s? For instance, not fish'ss or fish'..

Comment: I don't get your question.

Comment: If the string was "fish'sss" it would return "fish sss", but if it was fish's it would return fish's.

Comment: Should `fish'sss` return `fish sss` or `fishsss`?

Comment: the string should return fish sss. Using the code above when I send the string "fish'sss" i get back "fish'sss"

Comment: @lost9123193. You can't do this in a single replaceAll. You would need 2 - `A.replaceAll("'(?=s{2,})", " ").replaceAll("[^\\w' ]", "");`

Comment: This regex first replaces `'` followed by 2 or more `s`'s, with a whitespace. And then 2nd replace is same as previous one.